# Which kind of images is appropriate for VectorDrawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

[VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) is a new feature for Android after API Level 21, Which add support for *vectorgraph*. But I have a question for VectorDrawable, is it suitable for me to replace most of images in my project to VectorDrawable. In the android [offical dev site](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about) I saw a few words :

> A vector drawable is appropriate for simple icons. The material icons provide good examples of the types of images that work well as vector drawables in an app. In contrast, many app launch icons do have many details, so they work better as raster images.

Is that means `VectorDrawable` is only appropriate for **simple icons** like [offical material icons](https://design.google.com/icons/), images have many details aren't appropriate to use `VectorDrawable`.

Sorry for my poor english skills, hope you guys can understand me!

---

*I plan to use `VectorDrawable` for all my project image resource if it is ok.*

Answer (score 0):

You're basically right.

Vector images describe shapes and geometry, and need to be rendered into bitmaps (a grid of pixels). This requires some math, calculating the pixels that represent the lines and curves defined by the icon.

The more complicated an icon gets, means the more shapes that are required, and the more calculations that need to be done.

On the other side, if you already have the icon rendered to a specific scale, like with *png* images, all of the pixel values have already been calculated. Now it just needs to be converted to a bitmap and scaled to the size it gets displayed at.

So depending on the situation, an icon may be able to decode and scale from a png file faster than rendering from a vector drawable, or vice versa, it all depends on the icon.

It's hard to say exactly how simple an icon needs to be, so try it out and make sure it runs well on a range of devices.